# interaction between javascript (desktop application) and C#

Tags: c#, javascript, interaction

I am writing for my desktop some application for handling some services.
I wrote in C# an application that calculates something (lets call it cl.exe)
I created a .bat file that starts the cl.exe. 
I want to call that .bat file from my javascript so I WShell.Run(**.bat).

2 question:

1. The javascript program will not
   continue till the cl.exe will end ?
   (It is synchronized ?)
2. The cl.exe returns a value. How can
   the javascript take it (It is a
   javascript program that call .bat
   file that wrapp the execution of the
   cl.exe) ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about your architecture ? A Web page that launches a .bat file will work only on some specially configured environment.

Comment: No web page. Sime a windows script that runs on it and not on the web for dealing with administartation stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it wait, the 3rd parameter of WShell.Run should be set to true. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx

In that case, WShell.Run also returns the return value of the batch file. If I remember correctly, the bat file will return the error code from the last executable run. If not, you can set it with the batch `EXIT` command

Comment: Can you explain more how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To return the value, I used simple the System.Enviorment.Exit(TTT) whert TTT is the integer I wanted to return back.

When I started it I got all the time zero as an answear. I discovered that inorder the program be synchronaized it must be called differently.

WshShell.Run(exe file to be run, 3, true);

The true is here for to be synchronaized.

Comment: @Roman: this is not a discussion forum. Please edit your question with this new information instead of adding an answer.

Comment: But, for this there is the button "answear your question"